What is the difference between View.Backward and View.NavigateBackward in MS Visual Studio?
In MS Visual Studio what is the difference in behaviour between the commands "View.Backward" and "View.NavigateBackward"?
I can figure out "View.NavigateBackward" as it takes me to the previous cursor location in the text editor. I can also find it in the "View" menu.
I cannot figure out through experimentation, nor find out by searching, what "View.Backward" does. I cannot find it in the View menu. It does not change views, does not move the cursor, does not change tabs of open editors. I found the MS documentation here, but it is pretty scant:

View: global shortcuts
Backward  |    Alt+Left Arrow (Functions differently from View.NavigateBackward in Text Editor)   |    View.Backward

